# Como Abrir Cash Drawer conectada a una Receipt Printer por USB con c#

Tags: c#

Buenas Tardes, tengo un proyecto en c# que cuando imprima desde una impresora receipt conectada por usb tambien abra su gaveta de dinero que esta conecta ala impresora. he logrado que imprima pero no que abra el cash drawer.

detalles de impresora: NCR 7197 RECEIPT(esta tiene un puerto que se conecta la gaveta de dinero).

he intentado usar API´s (Windows.​Devices.​Point​Of​Service, ePOS-Print API) pero nome resulta funcional.

aqui le dejo enlace del proyecto:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6xiEbiG-Y0UWEd3TG1UUTMwZjA/view?usp=sharing